# ChromeDriverManager в фоновом режиме

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Возможно ли сюда как то передать  options.add_argument("--headless") для фонового запуска. Если делать по старинки options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() выскакивает ошибка DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
browser = webdriver.Chrome( Может у кого есть готовое решение

Comment: Может это ответит на ваш вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730392/sending-selenium-chrome-instance-to-the-background-using-python#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20programatic

Comment: Куда столько пакетов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из вашего вопроса, у вас не получается использовать опции с библиотекой `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`.

Если это так, то вот решение:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```