# WebDriver: Запуск большого количества потоков одновременно

Tags: python, selenium, вконтакте

Нужна помощь. Мне нужно создать бота для вк, обеспечивающий 100 одновременных обращений к системе с Web-интерфейсом. Каждое обращение идет под уникальным пользователем со своим логином и паролем. После логина эти пользователи должны выполнить одну и ту же операцию.

Я хочу это сделать на WebDriver, варианты с API исключены. Мне непонятно, как организовать одновременный запуск 100 аккаунтов. Можно ли это делать на одной машине? Не будут ли они мешать друг другу? Существует ли какое-то общепринятое и хорошо себя зарекомендовавшее решение для такого типа задач?

Answer (score 0):

Да, существует - pytest

Единственное, может не хватить оперативной памяти для запусков 100 одновременно браузеров, даже фоново. Дабы не столкнуться с синим экраном memError обдумайте)

Устанавливаете `pytest` и `pytest-xdist`, после этого в терминале прописываете:
`pytest -n 3` (Где `3` это количество одновременных запусков кейсов)

Ну и само собой 100 функций с введенными данными аккаунтов, каждая функция должна называться с `test_`.

Comment: немного дополню в тему большого потребления памяти, можно прокинуть аргумент браузера - "--headless", как прокинуть ответ есть тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452803/chromedrivermanager-в-фоновом-режиме